# Is paging and columnResizing not working in ui-grid v3.0.0-rc.11

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I can't seem to get any paging or column re-sizing working in the new ngGrid (ui-Grid) rc build v3.0.0-rc.11.  It should be really straight forward according to this example:  http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/401_AllFeatures

For my main div, if I do this:

```
<div ui-grid="productGridOptions"  ui-grid-resize-columns class="uiGridProducts">
```

and in my controller do this:

```
$scope.productGridOptions={};       


         $scope.productGridOptions.enableColumnResizing = true;
         $scope.productGridOptions.enableFiltering = false;
         $scope.productGridOptions.enablePaging = true;

         $scope.productGridOptions.pagingOptions = {
                    pageSizes: [250, 500, 1000],
                    pageSize: 250,
                    currentPage: 1
         };


         $scope.productGridOptions.rowIdentity = function(row) {
            return row.id;
          };

         $scope.productGridOptions.getRowIdentity = function(row) {
            return row.id;
         };

         $scope.productGridOptions.data = 'products';

        //The options for the data table    
        $scope.productGridOptions.columnDefs = [
                  { name:'ID', field: 'id' },
                  { name:'Product', field: 'productName' },
                  { name:'Active Ing.', field: 'activeIngredients'},
                  { name:'Comments', field: 'comments' }
                ];

        prProductService.getProducts().then(function(products) {
            $scope.products = products;



        });
```

Neither paging or column resizing work.  There are no paging examples on the ui-grid tutorial, so assume it is similar to ngGrid, but its column resizing which I really need at the moment.

Regards

i

Answer (score 17):

Well for column resizing, thanks to this link

http://technpol.wordpress.com/2014/08/23/upgrading-to-ng-grid-3-0-ui-grid/

apparently you have to add 'ui.grid.resizeColumns' as a dependency into your app module, and just use the ui-grid-resize-columns tag in the div (as I am doing)...

I removed the code

```
 $scope.productGridOptions.enableColumnResizing = true;
```

And column resizing is working now....

Now on to paging.

Regards

i

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks. I was looking at http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.resizeColumns.directive:uiGridColumnResizer which suggests using `ui-grid-column-resizer` attribute, but your suggesting of `ui-grid-resize-columns` attribute worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

Column resizing is working well for me. I had to add to add **'ui.grid.resizeColumns'** as a dependency:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.resizeColumns'])
```

Then in your html you add the **ui-grid-resize-columns class**:

```
<div class="grid" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-resize-columns></div>
```

And finally in your controller you set **enableColumnResizing** to **true** in **gridOptions**:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'data.data',
    enableSorting: true,
    enableColumnResizing: true
}
```

Hope that it finally works for you.

Extra info at: [angular-ui-grid column resizing](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/204_column_resizing)

Comment: This is similar to my own answer. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for earlier versions, but in ui-grid version 3.1.1 it is sufficient to add the ui.grid.resizeColumns dependency to your module and set enableColumnResizing = true in gridOptions. It's not necessary to add the ui-grid-resize-columns attribute to the div tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think pagination was added in v3.0.0-rc.12, but i'm not sure about that. Just search in the source file for pagination.

For handling pagination see this answer:

[Angular ui-grid tables, client side pagination and scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891312/angular-ui-grid-tables-client-side-pagination-and-scrolling/26862568#26862568)

There is also an example in the ui-grid-Tutorial:

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/214_pagination